# Specifying and assigning arguments of a function to be real

Tags: functions, complex, assumptions, variable-definitions, refine

I have the following complex matrix that I wish to integrate (element-by-element)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

MM[xp_, Δ_] := Simplify[{{I*xp^2 + 1/(Δ^2 + 1), I*Δ*E^(I*2*xp)}, {-I*Δ^2 + 1/(xp^2 + 1), -I*xp*E^(-I*2*Δ)}}, Assumptions -> {xp >= 0, xp ∈ Reals}];
PP[xx_, Δ_] := Simplify[Integrate[MM[y, Δ], {y, 0, xx}], Assumptions -> {xx >= 0, xx ∈ Reals}];

MM[x, Δ]
Simplify[PP[x, 0], Assumptions -> {x >= 0, x ∈ Reals}]
Refine[PP[x, 0], Element[x, Reals]]
```

In printing `PP[x,0]` irrespective of using `Simplify` or `Refine`, always give a `ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[x]],x!=0` for one of the matrix elements. My question is, how can I specify that the value of `x`, or any arguments of `MM` and `PP` to be real and remove any conditional expression?

**Edit:** This problem is an idealization of the actual problem that I want to ask, whereby instead of having a conditional expression for `x` (`x!=0`), I need to specify that `x` is real